# IE8 and IE9 MODAL ISSUE

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I am building a site, which can be seen here: http://alexconner.co.uk/marvel_2/index.html

But when you click the buttons to open the modal window, you can only see the flash animated background, not the contents of the window (this only happens in IE8 and IE9). I have a feeling it is something to do with the position:absolute in the CSS.

Comment: Post the relevant markup or a jsfiddle if possible.

Comment: Make sure your html is valid: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3a%2f%2falexconner.co.uk%2fmarvel_2%2findex.html